# Python, SqlAlchemy, push object into a list

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Tell me please, which best way do next thing:

I get user object something like this

```
user = User.query.filter(...).first()
resp = list(user)
return jsonify(resp)
```

Okay, it's ok if I just return user object, but when I wrapped user object into a list, I got `TypeError: User object is not iterablle`

Which best way, push user object into a `list`? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a list, with only one member, try 
`resp = [user]`

When you use `list(user)`, it tries to iterate over user, and create a list of each of the values returned.